# heroku django could not connect to server on db txn

Tags: python, django, heroku

I deployed my app on heroku, but when I do some DB operation, this is what I get:

```
Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I am using Postgres and defined all details in config vars:

```
DB_NAME=xx
DB_USER=xx
DB_PASSWORD=xx
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=5432
```

and the part of  code:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = form_signup(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        full_name = form.cleaned_data['full_name']
        username_email = form.cleaned_data['username_email']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password']
        user = User.objects.create_user(username_email,username_email,password)
return HttpResponse("Done")
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

On heroku your database does not run on localhost, but somewhere in the cloud.

Heroku exposes the postgres connection URL as `DATABASE_URL` in the environment variables (check `heroku config`).

You can use the `dj_database_url` package from kenneth reitz to auto parse it to django settings:

```
import dj_database_url

DATABASES = {
    'default': dj_database_url.config()
}
```

https://github.com/kennethreitz/dj-database-url